# In my programing I'm having it square a positive number but have it not square a negative. I'm confused on how to get it to loop through again

Tags: if-statement, while-loop

```
package com.mycompany.rooter;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Rooter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
int userNum = 0;
Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter positive number: ");
userNum = myObj.nextInt();
```

********while loop for square root. It only goes through once when I enter a positive number. How do I get it to loop through again so I don't have to run the program again? Otherwise, my code would be correct but I need it to loop through again to square other positive numbers. The programming language is java.****

```
while (userNum >= 1)
{
      
System.out.println(Math.sqrt(userNum));
       
if(userNum >= 1){
   
System.out.println("You successfully squared a positive integer!!! Congratulations user. Try 
again for more.");
break;
} if (userNum <=0) {
System.out.println("You entered a integer less than or equal to Zero. Please try again 
later.");
break;}
     
}
}
            
}
```

Comment: Good indentation is critical to minimizing "confusion".

Comment: I reworded what I said. Realized I worded it weird. I just need the while part and down to loop back to enter more than one number instead of re-running the code to enter another number.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can test a [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to see if the user entered an integer and then exit a while loop if there is none.

```
Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Please enter positive number: ");
    if (!myObj.hasNextInt()) {
       // print acknowledgement of terminating condition
       break;
    }
    int userNum = myObj.nextInt();
    if (userNum < 0) { // squaring zero should be allowed
       // print complaint
    } else {
       // print userNum squared
    }
}
```

Comment: For int userNum = myObj.nextInt(); netbeans says its already defined would I create int name; theb just change the userNum to a different name

Comment: When I change he coding that i have to yours I realised it does sqaure the input number

Comment: I just need help to loop back into the while statments